# How to make a component stay in that position where it is dragged and dropped in GrapesJS

Tags: grapesjs

How to make a component like image or text stay in the place where we dragged and dropped on the canvas. By default it is sitting at the top on the canvas every time we drag and drop. So how to allow it to move anywhere in the canvas as well.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/1936

Yes I found the answer here in this GitHub link which had the solution to this questions.